# Luna getNASA command not working for product MCD19A3D

Tags: r, terra

I wanted to download files for the NASA product [MCD19A3D](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mcd19a3dv061/) v061. When looking for products, it is only listed as MCD19A3, without a D. If I look up files available, it says none available, possibly because the D is missing. I have attached my code below, based on the tutorial on rspatial.org/modis/2-download.html and the getNASA() function description page.

How can I change something to make it work? Or should I try to write my own function to download files based on the URLs at https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD19A3D.061/

```
    library(luna)
    library(terra)
    library(geodata)
    senegal <- geodata::gadm("Senegal", level=1, path=".")

    available <- getNASA(product = "MCD19A3", version = "061", 
                         start_date = "2024-01-01", 
                         end_date = "2024-03-01",
                         aoi = senegal, 
                         download = FALSE,
                         path = path)
```

Comment: Following your link above (not using `luna`), if you go into NASA Earth Data search, put a rectangle around Senegal, and enter your dates, you have 55 files or your desired data, Jan 01 through about 2/27/2024. Might just be simpler to bulk download from there and continue with your research, possibly cropping each within `terra` to Senegal boundaries. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay!! I think that's what I'll have to do. Thanks :)

Comment: Doing an earth data search, then selecting files to download gives url for each file, stripping the http: to prevent translation here for one url: data.lpdaac.earthdatacloud.nasa.gov/lp-prod-protected/MCD19A3D.061/MCD19A3D.A2024001.h16v07.061.2024004193240/MCD19A3D.A2024001.h16v07.061.2024004193240.hdf

Comment: Oops, dang, have to rebuild my gdal with hdf driver(s).

Comment: And rebuilt GDAL with hdf4/hdf5 thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to find my EODIS logon info (you'll need yours), but this is a package that (should) simplify many steps that previously could prove quite frustrating, like creating a proper LDAAP url.

```
library(luna)
library(terra)

nasa_products[which(nasa_products$short_name == 'MCD19A3'), ][2,]
        provider             concept_id short_name version
46699 LPDAAC_ECS C1620265482-LPDAAC_ECS    MCD19A3     061
```

provider 'LDAAC_ECS' is the getNASA `server` that the query will be directed to (default value), `short_name` is `product` and version is version.

All of which sounds very nice, but, due to how selection of version(s) is coded, you won't get to version '061' as in the presence of multiple version, the first is used, in this case '006'.

```
f_list = luna::getNASA(product = 'MCD19A3', start_date = sdate, end_date = edate, aoi = senegal, version = '006', download = FALSE, username = usr, password = pwd,  server = 'LPDAAC_ECS')
[1] "No results found"

debugonce(getNASA)

f_list = luna::getNASA(product = 'MCD19A3', start_date = sdate, end_date = edate, aoi = senegal, version = '006', download = FALSE, username = usr, password = pwd,  server = 'LPDAAC_ECS')
# enter n 6 times
Browse[2]> h
        provider             concept_id short_name version
1912  LPDAAC_ECS C1000000540-LPDAAC_ECS    MCD19A3     006
46699 LPDAAC_ECS C1620265482-LPDAAC_ECS    MCD19A3     061

# now, entering s (for step), we see what code is going to be run
Browse[2]> s
debug: if (nrow(pp) < 1) {
    if (nrow(h) < 1) {
        stop("The requested product is not available for this through this function")
    }
    else {
        cat("Options for this product:\n")
        print(head(h, 10))
        cat("\n")
        stop("The requested product is not available for this product version or server")
    }
} else if (nrow(pp) > 1) {
    warning("Multiple sources available, using first one")
    print(pp)
    pp <- pp[1, ]
# and 1 is not 2
Browse[2]> h
        provider             concept_id short_name version
1912  LPDAAC_ECS C1000000540-LPDAAC_ECS    MCD19A3     006
46699 LPDAAC_ECS C1620265482-LPDAAC_ECS    MCD19A3     061
```

This will likely be fixed. The CMR STAC API in R [as presented in NASA tutorial](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/resources/e-learning/getting-started-with-nasas-cmr-stac-api-in-r/).

Comment: Thank you so much, and thanks for the link to the CMR STAC API in R. Right now, even in the 006 version there should be results for at least some dates, but it always somehow says no results available.... Gonna try using the tutorial to learn more.

Comment: Another answer that might give a general idea of the url one is trying to construct, though we want to populate further fields such as aoi, start and end dates [terra GDAL vsicurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605910/how-do-i-use-the-terra-r-package-with-cloud-optimized-geotiffs-requiring-authent).